# How do I compare 3+ lists/columns of data to identify multiple occurrences (to make a matrix)?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a matrix in Excel and I have struggled with coming up with a formula that works. I understand that it is easy to compare 2 lists (but not 4+ lists like I have)
This matrix is to identify whether an occurrence happens.

*Beginning Dataset:*

Buidling1 Building2 Building3 Building4 
NX1 ---- NX2 ---- NX1 ----  NX1 
NX3 ---- NX3 ---- NX3 ----  NX2 
(Blank)---- NX4 ---- (Blank) ---- NX3

*Example of the desired outcome (Option1):*

Building1 Building2 Building3 Building4 
NX1----(blank)----NX1----NX1 
(Blank)----NX2----(Blank)----NX2 
NX3-----NX3-----NX3-----NX3 
(Blank)----(Blank)----(Blank)----(Blank)

*Example of the desired outcome (Option2):*

----- Build1 Build2 Build3 Build4 
NX1 Yes-----(blank)-----Yes-----Yes 
NX2 (Bla)----Yes----(Bla)----Yes 
NX3 Yes------Yes------Yes------Yes 
NX4 (Bla)----NX4----(Bla)----(Bla)

Either option1 or option2 works fine.

Does anyone know an appropriate way for this to be done in excel or powerquery?

I have tried v-lookups and indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need a Countif:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,$F2),"Yes","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

Formulas:

```
=A2

=IF(B2=$F$2,"Yes","")
```

Results:

[image]